# App crashing on downloading the Image from it

Tags: java, android, download, crash

While Clicking on download button app is crashing and showing java.lang.NullPointerException

at com.$$$$$$.fieldforce.adapter.InstallDocAdapter.saveToGallery

Here is the logcat

```
Exception java.lang.NullPointerException:
  at android.graphics.Bitmap.compress (Bitmap.java:1434)
  at com.$$$$$$.fieldforce.adapter.InstallDocAdapter.saveToGallery (InstallDocAdapter.java:123)
  at com.$$$$$$.fieldforce.adapter.InstallDocAdapter.access$100 (InstallDocAdapter.java:40)
  at com.$$$$$$.fieldforce.adapter.InstallDocAdapter$1.onClick (InstallDocAdapter.java:75)
  at android.view.View.performClick (View.java:7488)
  at android.view.View.performClickInternal (View.java:7464)
  at android.view.View.access$3700 (View.java:841)
  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run (View.java:28911)
  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:938)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:99)
  at android.os.Looper.loopOnce (Looper.java:233)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:344)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:8212)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke
  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:584)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1034)
```

Here is the function used in it

```
private void saveToGallery(String attachment){
    byte [] encodeByte = Base64.decode(attachment,Base64.DEFAULT);
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(encodeByte, 0, encodeByte.length);

    FileOutputStream outputStream = null;
    File file = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    File dir = new File(file.getAbsolutePath() + "/$$$$$$ Downloads");
    dir.mkdirs();

    String filename = String.format("%d.png",System.currentTimeMillis());
    File outFile = new File(dir,filename);
    try{
        outputStream = new FileOutputStream(outFile);
    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG,100,outputStream);
    try{
        outputStream.flush();
    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try{
        outputStream.close();
        Toast.makeText(context,"Downloaded image ....",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

[Here is the screenshot of the above code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/42J9p.png)

Comment: `dir.mkdirs();` Replace by: if(!dir.exists()) if (!dir.mkdirs()) return; Display also a Toast() to inform the user.

Comment: try this ````if(!dir.exists()) {dir.mkdirs()}````

Comment: `catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }` Even if there is an exception you continue with compressing as if nothing had happened. Instead display a Toast() and stop.

Comment: There is nothing in your code that downloads anything.

Answer (score 0):

```
Exception java.lang.NullPointerException:
  at android.graphics.Bitmap.compress (Bitmap.java:1434)
  at com.$$$$$$.fieldforce.adapter.InstallDocAdapter.saveToGallery (InstallDocAdapter.java:123)
```

You're getting this because `saveToGallery` calls `Bitmap.compress` at *line 123* and passes *null* as a parameter that shouldn't be null. I'm assuming it's this line:

```
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG,100,outputStream);
```

The first two parameters are fine so it'll be `outputStream` that's null. Which means this:

```
try{
    outputStream = new FileOutputStream(outFile);
}catch (Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

is failing because an exception is being thrown, so `outputStream` (which is initialised as *null*) isn't being assigned.

[The docs for `FileOutputStream`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/FileOutputStream#FileOutputStream(java.io.File)) explain which exceptions are thrown under what circumstances, and you're printing the stacktrace to your logs in the catch block, so find out why it's failing. If you've made a mistake, fix it - if it's a valid scenario that *can happen*, then you need to handle that possibility in your code.